# SQL Copy Database failed. Now cannot see Database anymore

Tags: sql, sql-server

I attempted copying a database using the wizard and it failed halfway through. Then the original database disappeared from my SQL Management Studio explorer.

I am fearful that the database was dropped but, I know that Copy database does not drop, it just detaches then reattaches.  I am assuming it failed to reattach.

I attempted a restore and failed, and can see the Database listed, so I am sure it still exists.

Please tell me the Copy wizard did not drop my database!!!

Comment: Refreshes my web pages when something disappears

Comment: He is suggesting you refresh your database list.

Comment: Yes I did that and still no joy. Could it be that the failure of Copy kept the DB in a locked status and make it unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you used the faster Detach->Copy->Attach method, your database will still be out there. However, because the process failed in the middle of the process it may have never been re-attached.

You need to know where your data and log file(s) is/are. From there you open SSMS, right-click "Databases" and choose "Attach"

[image: attach]

then you'd need to select the proper data file

[image: files]

It should also find your log

[image: log]

but if it doesn't then you'll need to search for that as well.

Comment: That was exactly the way I attempted the copy. So you are saying that the DB was not dropped and still exists as a MDF? If so that is good news and will attempt that tomorrow.

Comment: @RyanLege yes. most likely.

Comment: @swashek One other question: One cannot restore a detached DB correct? It has to be attached? Because I attempted that and it errored on me.

Comment: @RyanLege i've not tested it but i'm not sure you can restore a database that has a datafile but no database. i dont know how the `WITH REPLACE, MOVE()` would work in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but here are some further suggestions to keep in mind:
1: Turn the computer off and on again to ensure SQL Management Studio is no longer running in the background (in some corrupted state).
2: Download some other database tool (such as Toad) and see if you can access the database.
3: Alternately, write a Java program that opens the database and reads a table to verify Java JDBC can access it.
4: Reload SQL Management Studio.
5: If SQL Management Studio partly copied your database to another location and that copy is corrupted, SQL Management Studio may hang on accessing that copy. See if you can locate it and delete the copy. You can find it by looking for a file extension that is the same as your database extension and is dated today (assuming your corruption happened today). Also see if SQL Managment Studio created other supporting files. Remove them too.

Comment: Thanks. I think swanshek with the above comment has the answer. I think that SQl Management studio somewhere in the detach process when it failed, will not show the DB held in a limbo state.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where renaming the database ( DbStaging -> DbLive ) and trying to copy it after resulted in a delete of the database DbLive. Basically, I wanted to have a copy of the now DbLive but naming the clone DbStaging (back) and got a conflict with the MDF file, and had to restore a backup from a week in the past.

Renaming the database doesn't rename the MDF file and when the Copy is attempted get's into conflict because an MDF file already exists, crashes, and in the attempt to rollback, deletes the good database. Learn this the hard way...